# How to disable events

Tags: openlayers-3

How to disable or hide the events of a feature that are under an overlay? The event "map.on ( 'SingleClick'" is well off but not the "event map.on (' pointermove'" of the marker below the overlay.

Do you have an idea ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you create a small JSFiddle live example out of this ?  I'd be interested to play with this to look for the answer.  Oh, and if you could also clarify what you're trying to do it would be nice.  I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: The tooltip of the marker that is below the overlay appears when moving the cursor over the marker that is below. [example] (http://www.mides.fr/geocaching/fullmapmerimeetls/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you could do.  In the method called when the `pointermove` event occurs, you could check the values of the following properties:

- `evt.originalEvent.target` - that is always equal to the dom element being the target of the event.  For example, while mouse hovering the popup it can be equal to `<div id="popup-content">...</div>`
- `evt.originalEvent.currentTarget` - that will always be equal to the viewport div of openlayers

What you could do is this: do nothing when `evt.originalEvent.target` is not the OpenLayers' viewport.

### Update 2016-04-13

I had to do something quite similar.  I had an overlay in a map and I wanted to prevent the `pointermove` from occurring below it.  Here's what I did:

```
var target = evt.originalEvent.target;
if ($(this.getElement()).has(target)) {
  evt.coordinate = [Infinity, Infinity];
  evt.pixel = [Infinity, Infinity];
}
```

In the above, `this` represents the `ol.Overlay` object.  The idea is to override the coordinate and pixel properties of the event, which makes the rest of the interactions act as I wanted: do nothing.

Comment: From your idea I have another idea I don't know if that's a good thing to do.
(http://www.mides.fr/geocaching/fullmapmerimeetls/)

if (evt.originalEvent.target.id == container.id || evt.originalEvent.target.id == content.id){
   tooltip.innerHTML = "";
   return;
}

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre Dubé for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var container = document.getElementById('popup');    
...
container.onmousemove = function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    tooltip.innerHTML = "";
};
```